# Java BigDecimal Rounding up to two decimal places

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am trying to round off BigDecimal in Java below is the code that I executed

```
   BigDecimal prec1 = new BigDecimal("49.3249999999999999990")
                             .setScale( 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
   BigDecimal prec2 = new BigDecimal("49.3249999999999999990")
                             .setScale( 3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                             .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

So the output are prec1 = 49.32 and prec2 = 49.33 for my use case I need always to round off to 49.33 so is there any other way to round off to 49.33 other than setting scale two times ? also I am using the HALF_UP for all the computations, I can't got for CEILING or UP, I have to follow the rule for half up (eg: round off to 1 if value is greater than or equal .5 ) So following this rule is there any way to achieve the mentioned result?

Comment: `49.3249999999999999990` rounds to `49.32`. The only way you can make it round to `49.33` in a single step is by rounding a different number, e.g. by adding something to it before rounding.

Comment: `RoundingMode.UP`? `RoundingMode.CEILING`?

Comment: What is the actual rule here? There's a RoundingMode of 'UP' and that will get you what you want in these cases. But what is your rule?

Comment: If 49.324999 with scale 2 should become 49.33 `UP` would apply meaning even 49.32411 might yield 49.33 a kind of ceiling value away from 0 (negative numbers).

Comment: These are not `BigInteger` but `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I am a bit confused as to why "`49.3249999999999999990` rounds to `49.32`". Could you elaborate a bit? I would have expected `49.3249999999999999990` to round to `49.325` for three decimals and therefore to two `49.33` for two decimals. What am I missing?

Comment: @Koenigsberg [run it and see](https://ideone.com/v9445F).

Comment: @AndyTurner I think there is some fundamental misunderstanding with regard to rounding in my mind. Prior to posting I  got the same result on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=round+49.3249999999999999990+to+2+decimal+places), though I do not understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Koenigsberg it's closer to 49.32 than it is to 49.33.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah, I see now. The half-threshold is simply not exceeded. I think both OP and me used the same erroneous way of thinking which is why they expected the same result for `prec1` and `prec2`. The way of thinking was to round the nines which shifts the overall value to `49.325`. This should then have resolved to `49.33`. I can see now why this is incorrect. This may solve OP's problem as well.

Comment: 0.49999999999990 is less than a half. Mathematically of course 0.499999... recurring **is** a half. But 0.49999999999990 is definitely <0.5 and definitely rounds down on round half up rules.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. It is rounding half-up as expected as normally defined.
That is such that 0.49999999999999990<0.5 so rounds down because it rounds down below 0.5 (a half).

I believe the OP has misunderstood the rule and just needs to use the ordinary `HALF_UP` rounding mode.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    
    BigDecimal value=new BigDecimal("49.3249999999999999990");
    BigDecimal mark=new BigDecimal("49.325");//Values less than this round down!
    BigDecimal down=new BigDecimal("49.32");
    boolean expectDown;
    
    if(value.compareTo(mark)<0){
        System.out.println(value + " is less than "+mark);
        System.out.println("So rounds down");
        expectDown=true;
    }else{
        System.out.println(value + " is greater than or equal to "+mark);
        System.out.println("So rounds up");
        expectDown=false;
    }
    BigDecimal result=value.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("Rounded to "+result);
    if(result.equals(down)==expectDown){
        System.out.println("As expected");  
    }else{
        System.out.println("NOT As expected!!!");
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
49.3249999999999999990 is less than 49.325
So rounds down
Rounded to 49.32
As expected
```